# How to sum values grouped by two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2017-1-1', '2017-1-1', '2017-1-2', '2017-1-2', '2017-1-3'],
    'Groups': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two'],
    'data': range(1, 6)})

    Date      Groups     data  
0  2017-1-1    one       1
1  2017-1-1    one       2
2  2017-1-2    one       3
3  2017-1-2    two       4
4  2017-1-3    two       5
```

How can I generate a new DataFrame like this:

```
    Date       one     two 
0  2017-1-1    3        0
1  2017-1-2    3        4
2  2017-1-3    0        5
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) was made for this:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='Groups',aggfunc=sum)
```

results in

```
         data
Groups    one  two
Date
2017-1-1  3.0  NaN
2017-1-2  3.0  4.0
2017-1-3  NaN  5.0
```

Personally I find this approach much easier to understand, and certainly more pythonic than a convoluted groupby operation.  Then if you want the format specified you can just tidy it up:

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df.columns.name = None
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

which gives you

```
       Date  one  two
0  2017-1-1  3.0  0.0
1  2017-1-2  3.0  4.0
2  2017-1-3  0.0  5.0
```

Comment: Nice! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Josh D.  This's cool and straightforward! I agree that it takes some brain power to figure out how groupby works. Thank you!

Comment: What I am wondering about is that it is not necessary to mention the column which should be summed, correct?

Answer (score 9):

Pandas black magic:

```
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Groups']).sum().sum(
    level=['Date', 'Groups']).unstack('Groups').fillna(0).reset_index()

# Fix the column names
df.columns = ['Date', 'one', 'two']
```

Resulting `df`:

```
       Date  one  two
0  2017-1-1  3.0  0.0
1  2017-1-2  3.0  4.0
2  2017-1-3  0.0  5.0
```

Comment: Holy! The black magic is so powerful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! See the updated answer; I simplified the expression and added a fix for the column names to be exactly as requested.

Comment: I think your previous version has its advantage since it can be applied to other more complicated data sets. I copied it here: df.groupby(['Date', 'Groups', 'data'])['data'].sum().sum(level=['Date', 'Groups']).unstack('Groups').fillna(0)

Comment: @Kevin If this or any future answer solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A (perhaps slightly more idiomatic) alternative to @tuomastik's answer:

```py
df.groupby(['Date', 'Groups']).sum().unstack('Groups', fill_value=0).reset_index()
```